# Load styles in Google Maps Wizard

Tags: google-maps, wizard

Im using the [Google Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) to customize the color of some maps I need to embed on an website.

I got some JSON that loads ok but if I need to make a change I need to touch the code and load the map every time I change a value to see the results.

Is there any way I can load the styles I already have on a .js file into the Google Maps Wizard or is there any third party tool that allow me to do that?

Comment: Surpirsed no-one has attempted to re-create a better version of the styled maps wizard.  The current one lacks ability to save, or see other templates, or import JSON, or edit the colour values, etc

Comment: agree, need the ability to import JSON otherwise all work is lost on page load!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.mapstylr.com/ is a better solution. It has a load option so you can paste your current style and continue with it.

Besides, it lets you save the map and publish it. They have a showcase to browse and download styles other people did.

Answer (score 4):

Just stumbled upon [this Github project](https://github.com/Instrument/styled-maps-wizard) which is a version of the original [styled maps wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) *with* json import functionality:

http://instrument.github.io/styled-maps-wizard/

Comment: Thats awesome. I was injecting the JSON via console but this is much better. =)